# Why does WPF Popup PlacementRectangle cause clipping?

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF application I am working on, I have icons on a map that show a context menu in a Popup when clicked.  Since I want to align the context menu below the icon, I use `PlacementRectangle` with the rectangle of the icon image and `Placement.Bottom`.

This works fine most of the time, but a few of the icons have context menus that are more than half the height of the screen (on a 1024x768 screen), and when close to the edge of the screen the Popups are getting clipped after being aligned to the edge.

I have read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on this several times over, but don't see an explanation for the behavior I am seeing.
Specifically, the behavior I am seeing is:

When the icon is near center of the screen, but too low for the menu to fit below it, the Popup gets flipped to the top of the icon as expected (Target Origin & Popup Alignment Point change).  When the resulting flip puts the top of the popup past the top edge of the screen, the top of the popup is re-aligned with the screen as expected.  The bottom edge of the Popup, however, does not get shifted downwards with the rest of the Popup, resulting in clipping the bottom content of the Popup (while there is plenty of room to expand).  This seems to counter the reason it gets shifted to the edge of the screen in the first place ("for security concerns"...).

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I would expect all of this behavior to be the same except for the clipping at the end, and If I use `Placement.Mouse` or `Placement.MousePoint`, the whole Popup shifts correctly.

I can find no explanation for this behavior in the msdn docs or from google searches, is this a bug or expected behavior?  Is there a workaround or trick for using PlacementRectangle and preventing the resulting clipping?

I created a simple WPF example app to demonstrate the problem.  It is simply a window with a canvas that contains a rectangle named "Rec".  The code has a single event handler:

```
    private void Window_MouseDown( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
    {
        // get mouse coordinates at click
        var c = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        var cs = PointToScreen(c);

        // an image to visualize popup clipping
        var img = new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage( new Uri( "pack://application:,,,/test.png" ) ) };
        img.Width = 150;
        img.Height = 500;

        // visually show the placement rectangle
        Canvas.SetLeft( Rec, c.X );
        Canvas.SetTop( Rec, c.Y );

        var p = new Popup()
        {
            Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom,
            PlacementRectangle = new Rect( cs.X, cs.Y, 40, 60 ),
            //Placement = PlacementMode.Mouse,
            StaysOpen = false,
            Child = img,
        };

        p.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

**NOTE:** I tried using a PlacementTarget and got the same clipping behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has answered this and I haven't found any more information on the issue, I'm guessing this is a bug.  I have found a workaround, which I thought I would post in case anyone else ran into it:

Using a custom placement with a placement callback lets you mimic the expected behavior of the Popup and does not perform any clipping:

```
    var p = new Popup()
    {
        PlacementRectangle = new Rect( cs.X, cs.Y, 40, 60 ),
        Placement = PlacementMode.Custom,
        CustomPopupPlacementCallback = new CustomPopupPlacementCallback( placePopup ),
        StaysOpen = false,
        Child = img,
    };
```

And the placement callback i used:

```
private CustomPopupPlacement[] placePopup( Size popupSize, Size targetSize, Point offset )
{
    Debug.WriteLine( "{0}; {1}; {2}", popupSize.ToString(), targetSize.ToString(), offset.ToString() );
    return new[] { 
        new CustomPopupPlacement( new Point( -50, targetSize.Height ), PopupPrimaryAxis.Vertical ),
        new CustomPopupPlacement( new Point( -50, -popupSize.Height ), PopupPrimaryAxis.Vertical ),
    };
}
```